# Tooltip not working when having more than one

Tags: javascript, tooltip

First of all, sorry, because I'm sure is gonna be some silly thing.

I have this code in which I would like to display images when hovering a text. Doing this on tooltip, everything seems fine, but the tooltip is just working on the first one. Should I create classes for each one?

HTML:

```
<div title="regular tooltip">Description:

<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
    Tooltip 1
    <span id="tooltip-span">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    </span>
</a>

/

<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
    Tooltip 2
    <span id="tooltip-span">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    </span>
</a>


</div>
```

JS:

```
var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-span');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
```

CSS:

```
.tooltip {
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip span {
    display:none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Linking to the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/javierestebanx/HJf8q/3430/

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: document.getElementById('tooltip-span'); id should be unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick solution using a class instead of an id. When you use multiple times the same id, only the first one will be selected, that's why the second one didn't move in your original code.

`getElementsByClassName` gets a `HTMLCollection`, so you have to loop on the elements inside.

```js
var tooltipSpans = document.getElementsByClassName('tooltip-span');

window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY,
        i, l = tooltipSpans.length;
    for(i = 0; i < l; i++){
      tooltipSpans[i].style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
      tooltipSpans[i].style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
    }
};
```

```css
.tooltip {
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip span {
    display:none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div title="regular tooltip">Description:

<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
    Tooltip 1
    <span class="tooltip-span">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    </span>
</a>

/

<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
    Tooltip 2
    <span class="tooltip-span">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    </span>
</a>


</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-span');
var tooltipSpan1 =document.getElementById('tooltip-span2');
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
 tooltipSpan1.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan1.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
```

```css
.tooltip {
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip span ,.tooltip span2{
    display:none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div title="regular tooltip">Description:

<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
    Tooltip 1
    <span id="tooltip-span">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    </span>
</a>

/

<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
    Tooltip 2
    <span id="tooltip-span2">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    </span>
</a>


</div>
```

`id="tooltip-span"` is used twice in the DOM. it should be unique. You can create separate ID or use className and bind onmousemove event.the preview is with two ID

Answer (score 0):

The id's of span need to be unique. Here is the working code

**HTML:**

```
<div title="regular tooltip">Description:

<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
    Tooltip 1
    <span id="tooltip-span1">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    </span>
</a>

/

<a class="tooltip" href="http://www.google.com/">
    Tooltip 2
    <span id="tooltip-span2">
        <img alt="" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
    </span>
</a>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.tooltip {
    text-decoration:none;
    position:relative;
}
.tooltip span {
    display:none;
}
.tooltip:hover span {
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**JS:**

```
var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-span1');
var tooltipSpan2 = document.getElementById('tooltip-span2');
window.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x = e.clientX,
        y = e.clientY;
    tooltipSpan.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan2.style.top = (y + 20) + 'px';
    tooltipSpan2.style.left = (x + 20) + 'px';
};
```

Hopefully this is what you need.

Comment: Exactly what I needed and works also perfectly. Although I rather use @kaddath solution, this code will potentially be a "listing" and seems easier to not having to create unique span id's. Thank you so much anyway! :)